# Void value not ignored as it ought to be, c, arduino

Tags: arduino

got a school project and I'm using NRF24L01+ transceivers with arduinos. 
Found [this how to](https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/Nrf24L01-2.4GHz-HowTo) but when I copy down the respective codes (transmit and receive), but the latter won't compile. I get the error in the title. I know it's been asked before, sorry.

```
bool done = false;
while (!done)
{
  // Fetch the data payload
  done = radio.read( joystick, sizeof(joystick) );
  Serial.print("X = ");
  Serial.print(joystick[0]);
  Serial.print(" Y = ");      
  Serial.println(joystick[1]);
```

Comment: Which line is the error in?

Comment: We don't what Serial is. Nor radio. Nor joystick.  And we can't see which line the error is on.  Also, this smells more like C++ than C.

Comment: Does `radio.read` return a value?

Comment: Which "void value is ignored" are you talking about? All you have done is copy pasted one fragment from the source you linked.

Comment: @WeatherVane `radio.read` return type is `void`.

Comment: @ouah he's copied the example: which also takes it as `bool`

Comment: @WeatherVane http://playground.arduino.cc/InterfacingWithHardware/Nrf2401 look at read function

Comment: @ouah an answer from you then?

Comment: @WeatherVane still not clear for me without the full sources, he may have included the wrong include files.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this is neither C nor C++ ... arduino should be considered a language of its own ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen `avr-g++` is used for compilation, C++.

Comment: @ouah the reference manual says "The Arduino language is based on C/C++.". This is as vague as it could be ... maybe it's "just" an extension, but still, having some global objects defined etc, it looks quite different from C++. (it says further "The Arduino language (based on Wiring) is implemented in C/C++" -- whatever *that* should mean)

Comment: The problem is not in the code you posted, it's probably in some part you wrote. That error is really common when you try to assign the result of a void function

If it's trully giving an error inside those lines please add the full error and in which line it is

Comment: @FelixPalmen It's a variation of C++, but you can use pure C as well (Not recommended, but possible), that's why it says is based on C/C++ (I don't like the term either)

Comment: @Mr.E Alright, but even if it's "just" C++ with a defined runtime providing several global object instances, it will look confusing in at least the [tag:c] tag and maybe even in the [tag:c++] tag.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Totally agree, this should only be tagged as "Arduino"

Comment: void loop()   /****** LOOP: RUNS CONSTANTLY ******/
{
  if ( radio.available() )
  {
    // Read the data payload until we've received everything
    bool done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
      // Fetch the data payload
      done = radio.read( joystick, sizeof(joystick) );
      Serial.print("X = ");
      Serial.print(joystick[0]);
      Serial.print(" Y = ");      
      Serial.println(joystick[1]);
    }
  }
  else
  {    
      Serial.println("No radio available");
  } Error is in " done = radio.read( joystick, sizeof(joystick) );" full code is in the link in the first post.

Answer (score 1):

The library you're using is the RF24 from TMRh20 (https://github.com/TMRh20/RF24). And as you can see in the header file RF24.h (https://github.com/TMRh20/RF24/blob/master/RF24.h, line 203) the function read is of type void. Trying to assign a variable to a void function, produces the error

Apparently the library got updated and return types changed. Your code should change like this:

```
void loop(){
    while (radio.available(joystick))
    {
      // Fetch the data payload
      radio.read( joystick, sizeof(joystick) );
      Serial.print("X = ");
      Serial.print(joystick[0]);
      Serial.print(" Y = ");      
      Serial.println(joystick[1]);
    }
}
```

I never used this library, soy you should test if this is correct, but just by reading the documentation (Which you should always do, and not just copy-pasta) it seems like how it should be done